# Why the On Click() Function in UI Button Is not Triggered?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm making a VR game , the game has a UI canvas that has 2 Buttons inside it.
The pointer interacts when i hover the pointer on the buttons,also the buttons change color,however when i click on the button ..it doesn't trigger the function.

Here is an image of the scene:

[image]

That's the on click() reference of the "bullet" botton:

[image: That's the on click() reference of the "bullet" botton]

The Player script that has the shot() function is on the main camera

and that's the shot function in it

```
public void Shot()
{
    Debug.Log("isEntered");
    isSeek = false;
}
```

and  i'm using

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

for the Player class

why when i press on the button Shot ,Shot function is not triggered ?

Comment: there isnt really enough info to answer.. do you get errors? is the button disabled?

Comment: @BugFinder The button is not disabled and i have only one warning: "Virtual Reality SDK Cardboard is not supported in Editor Play Mode. Please Build and run on a supported target device.
Will attempt to enable None instead."

Comment: @BugFinder the buttons are enabled by default right? i didn't change in their "interactable"

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjbQX.png)

check if you had set this option

Comment: i had set it before ,it had no difference

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more of information.

Does the button change color on click? (it will let us know if the problem is with clicking or the button itself). I mean not highlighted color change, but pressed.

[image]

Full canvas, camera, button parameters would be informative too.

Comment: the button is highlighted when i click on it